# Proximity of a DC / DC converter and operational amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, emc

There is an operational amplifier [LM258WYDT](https://ru.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/lm158w-954928.pdf), which outputs a signal with a frequency of 1 kHz. It is powered by an [TMR1222](https://assets.tracopower.com/20191030133135/TMR2/documents/tmr2-datasheet.pdf) isolated DC/DC converter, which produces +12/-12V.

[image]

For example, the DC/DC converter is located at the upper level of the board, and the operational amplifier is at the lower level. Between them is a ground polygon.

[image]

How is this arrangement in terms of noise? Can a DC/DC converter affect the operation of an operational amplifier?

Thanks!

Comment: Difficult to say, but Traco parts certainly are known for emitting quite a bit of noise depending on the part and load.

Comment: How clean must the OpAmp output be? what is the input signal level and source impedance, to the OpAmp? Inside the switcher, you have 10 volts in 10 nanosecond edges; that will capacitively and magnetically couple into the OpAmp; 10mA in 10nS is 1Million amps/second dI/dT; assuming 1cm^2 receiver loop, 1cm away, the injected Hfield voltage is 2e-10 * dI/dT or 2e-10 * 1e+6 = 200 microVolts, ignoring some natural-log factors in the HFI model (that probably are important at this close topology) --- 200 microVolts at 10 nanosecond edges. Are you depending on the opamp being SLOW, to reject?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. Your "isolation" appears to be only suited for smallish DC or low frequency/low voltage AC voltages, based on the continuation of the ground plane connected to the input power source under the op-amp.

If that's the intention you might benefit from a capacitor in the tens of nF bridging the DC-DC to conduct the switching noise to the input source.

Answer (score 1):

The min switching frequency of the TMR1022 is 100kHZ and up to 650kHz, this is the range of noise that could couple.

But with the arrangement above, very little noise will be able to couple from top to bottom because the ground plane (I assume it's continuous) acts like a shield to prevent capacitive coupling.

A more direct pathway for noise is the ripple on the VCC line, the PSRR of the LM258 is 115dB, so the ripple will be reduced considerably (~50mV of ripple would be ~100nV of noise on the output).

My thought's are anything with PWM the tolerace for noise is probably high. Another option is if your bandwidth tolerates it, you could low pass filter out any noise above 100kHz in the opamp feedback loop, and that would also prevent a lot of noise.

Use a bypass capaictor on the opamp.